# Ionic 2 refresher is not working over IFRAME

Tags: iframe, ionic-framework, ionic2, pull-to-refresh

I am developing a web app using IONIC 2. the home component contains an iframe with full width and height. The Refresher is working fine when I pull down outside the IFRAME but when I pull down over the IFRAME to refresh the app then Refresher it doesn’t work,

So I want that when any user pull down over the IFRAME the Refresher should work also.

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        I did not use ion-refresher with IFRAME but i'm using this ion-refresher 
        in a page
        like this at top of page ---
        ===== this is a html part ====
        <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="refreshFollowFeed($event)">
            <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
          </ion-refresher>

    ========= ts part ===========

     refreshFollowFeed(event) {
        console.log('here your api part');
        === and add setTimeout section  where api hit successfully.
        setTimeout(() => {
          event.complete();
        }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: it's working fine in the app but the not over the iframe